# Elastic APM Agent PHP - Transaction still not ended

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastic-apm

I have a Laravel app connected to a APM Server with the following route to test it connection:

```
use Elastic\Apm\ElasticApm;

Route::get('/test', function () {
  $transaction = ElasticApm::beginCurrentTransaction(
    'HomeController@index',
    'request'
  );

  $transaction->end();
  return view('welcome');
});
```

In app terminal I'm getting this message:

*[beginTransactionWithBuilder] Received request to begin a new current transaction even though there is a current transaction that is still not ended*

I'm following every step of [elastic APM Agent for PHP](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/php/current/intro.html)

Basically I want to finish every running transaction, but didn't found any method to do it